# What response status code should I return?

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, stateless

I am having a simple shoppinglist app where users can create a shoppinglist, view a shopping list and even share a shopping list. My problem is given that a User has not created a shopping list lets say `x` but it has been created by another user and therefore it is in the database, what status code should I return to this User who didn't create this Shoppinglist? Should it be a `403` since it is in the database but this user has no permission to view it or should it be `404` since it does not exist in this user collection of shopping lists.

Comment: Make the path relative to the user, e.g. `/users/{userId}/lists/{listId}`. Then there's no doubt that `/users/{user1Id}/lists/{user2listId}` is 404, or that user1 accessing `/users/{user2Id}/lists/{anything}` is 403. Semantically, if the resource does exist but the current user shouldn't see it, that's 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return 404: the user shouldn't know about another cart with the same ID that is owned by a different user.

Returning 403 is considered a security flow because then a malicious hacker can start hitting your APIs with consecutive user-ids and until they find the user which owns the cart.

Comment: In this case the shopping lists are just added to the database and related to a user using a `owned_by` field in the shopping_list object there is nothing like a shopping list cart for a user. Will your answer still be the same in this case??

Comment: Yes, my answer still stands regardless what name you choose to give this object.

Comment: It's actually easier for you to implement since you can set your query to check `owned_by` as well as the cart-id. This means that the query will return an empty set of result and your application will "naturally" respond with 404.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is perfectly fine, an alternative is to send 403 for every ID, even if it doesn't exist. That way there's no security hole either. I am assuming the user is identified through authentication and know that /lists/200 is theirs, therefore IDs up to 200 probably exist. If both /lists/50 and /lists/50000000 both return 403, the user is none the wiser.

This behaviour might be safer in the face of intermediaries like caching proxies, which can cache 404s publicly but not 403 responses.